# Вопрос по отступам css

Tags: html, css

У меня есть страница с меню, задний фон - фотография. Я хочу сделать отступления меню сверху страницы, но когда задаю margin-top у меня не делается отступление меню сверху, а оно берет весь header и делает отступление с начала страницы. В чем моя ошибка ???

HTML

```
<header class="header">
<div lassc="menu">
<div><a href="#">PRICING</a></div>
<div><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></div>
<div><a href="#">ABOUT</a></div>
<div><a href="#">LOGIN</a></div>
<div><a href="#">SIGN IN</a></div>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');

*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.header {
height: 939px;
background-image: url(./images/image.png);
}

.menu{
display: flex;
column-gap: 27px;
font-weight: bold;
width: 414px;
height: 31px;
margin-top: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузер все делает правильно так как `margin` это внешний отступ. Поэтому внешний отступ и есть снаружи. Вам надо меню присвоить `padding-top` внутренний отступ сверху.

Comment: Йой, я даже и не подумал. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Тут море различных решений на самом деле.

Пара вариантов:

1. Добавить в `.header` `overflow:hidden`
2. Заменить `margin-top` на `padding-top`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, для элемента `header` задать `padding` сверху и снизу.